# Hang in Microsoft.Identity.Client trying to acquire auth token interactively the second time

Tags: c#, azure, desktop-application, azure-ad-msal

I'm doing a Azure AD connection from a C# Windows Forms project(.NetFramework 4.8) via Mailkit, I successfully connected one time but after try the connection again, code just hanging on the that line;

var authToken = await publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

If i run same code on a Console project it's everytime working and opening outlook frame, but on my project it's not working correctly now. Can anyone help me emergency ?

I'm sharing my code from gist to yours.

[My Code Lines on Gist](https://gist.github.com/emreozguruoglu/26afc7754292a3fd590939532c965c8b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your current issue, which is that your application does not execute as planned after the initial token run. I recommend thoroughly debugging your application to determine the specific issue and sharing it with us so we can investigate further.

For further guidance here is a walkthrough with a sample:
https://cmatskas.com/modern-authentication-with-azure-ad-for-winforms-native-apps-2/

Comment: Thanks @Rutha, That was a good suggestion for me.